# Как совместить два коллайдера в один

Tags: unity3d, 2d

создаю 2D-платформер и столкнулась с такой проблемой, на моем персонаже находится два коллайдера (прямоугольник и круг), и триггер для каждого из них срабатывает по отдельности, то есть персонаж получает двойной урон (т.к. триггер срабатывает для двух коллайдеров). Понимаю, что решением является создание отдельного GameObject(пускай CharacterColliders) и поместив в него 2 коллайдера, но не понимаю, что делать дальше.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас указан тэг 2d, поэтому одним из вариантов будет использовать специальный [Composite Collider 2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-CompositeCollider2D.html), который объединяет несколько иных коллайдеров в один сложной формы. По ссылке описано, как нужно их настраивать.

Comment: А возможно ли объединить circle и box коллайдеры с помощью composit-a?

Comment: @Stasia, обычно подразумевается, что `PolygonCollider`-а должно хватать на все. `Box` в списке просто для простоты. Сделайте кружок из полигонального - там можно самому ставить точки, либо он сам вам их расставит по форме спрайта

Answer (score 0):

Одним из вариантов будет замена всех коллайдеров одним Polygon Collider 2D. Вам необходимо будет вручную задать форму коллайдера в Inspector, но в итоге у вас получится один цельный коллайдер, который будет реагировать на событие только один раз.
Если же вам необходимо использовать несколько отдельных коллайдеров (например, для обработки попадания в голову персонажа), вы можете добавить отдельный коллайдер.

Подробная документация Polygon Collider 2D доступна здесь: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PolygonCollider2D.html